# How to reduce response time for sequelize for multiple one to many relationship?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using the sequelize ORM with express JS. And one of the api end point require data pertaining to Parent Table with lots of Child Table. Here is the sample model file

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const { sequelize } = require('../someplace');

const Parent = sequelize.define(
  'Parent',
  {
    id: {
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    parentOneThing: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    parentAnotherThing: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    
  },
  {
    tableName: 'Parent',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_date',
    updatedAt: 'modified_date',
    version: false,
    paranoid: false
  }
);



Parent.hasMany(Child1, {
  foreignKey: 'id',
  targetKey: 'id'
});

Parent.hasMany(Child2, {
  foreignKey: 'id',
  targetKey: 'id'
});

Parent.hasMany(Child3, {
  foreignKey: 'id',
  targetKey: 'id'
});

Parent.hasMany(Child4, {
  foreignKey: 'id',
  targetKey: 'id'
});

Parent.hasMany(Child5, {
  foreignKey: 'id',
  targetKey: 'id'
});

Parent.hasMany(Child6, {
  foreignKey: 'id',
  targetKey: 'id'
});

Parent.hasMany(Child7, {
  foreignKey: 'id',
  targetKey: 'id'
});

Parent.hasMany(Child8, {
  foreignKey: 'id',
  targetKey: 'id'
});

Parent.hasMany(Child9, {
  foreignKey: 'id',
  targetKey: 'id'
});
```

Here is my get all parents data for a give id array:

```
const Parents = await Parent.findAll(
    {
      where: {
        id: someIdArray
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: Child1,
          separate: true,
        },
        {
          model: Child2,
          separate: true,
        },
        {
          model: Child3,
          separate: true,
        },
        {
          model: Child4,
          separate: true,
        },
        {
          model: Child5,
          separate: true,
        },
        {
          model: Child6,
          separate: true,
        },
        {
          model: Child7,
          separate: true,
        },
        {
          model: Child8,
          separate: true,
        },
        {
          model: Child9,
          separate: true,
        },
        
      ],
      
    },
    { transaction }
  );
```

What can be the best approach for handling such requirements?

I have tried it with separate false as well.

Separate false takes too much time since it takes time for sequalize to un-duplicate the data because of the outer join. Separate true take considerable less time but still is not good enough.

I have also tried lazy loading but that takes almost same time as separate false.

I want to make the most time efficient call.

The DB has indexes in primary key of the tables and clustered unique index with foreign key and primary. DB is MSSQL

Comment: How many records in all tables? Can you write the stats in the post?

Comment: try first to write the sql query and check if it differs

Comment: I have tried the query that are shown in both separate true and false, and they take about2-3 seconds. While the response is taking 10 seconds in average.